# How to solve issue of single quote in filer value using DataTable.Select()

Tags: c#, sql

Assuming I want `productCode` variable below to be assigned the product code of a product named `Cookie's`

NOTE the "'" in the the `ProductName` because it is the one causing the statement below to fail. Basically, the "'" in the filter expression makes for wrong SQL syntax.

I would appreciate any ideas from you guys.

```
DataTable dt=PullSomeDataFromProductTableDatabase();
string filterValue="Cookie's";
string productCode=dt.Select("[ProductName]='"+filterValue+"'")[0]["ProductCode"]
```

Line (3) fails because its the same thing as saying

```
Select ProductCode from Products Where ProductName='Cookie's';
```

This introduces 3 single quotes in the filter expression. Hence error. Note that `FilterValue` is meant to be dynamic later in my code

Comment: put extra single quote like 'Cookie''s'

Answer (score 4):

Try `string filterValue="Cookie''s";`

or

`string filterValue="Cookie'+CHAR(39)+'s";`

Comment: Yes it is. filterValue is a constant variable. If not - your filterValue.Replace("'", "''") of course will be a better solution

Comment: My values are dynmaic String.Replace() works beautifully. Thanks Andrey.

Answer (score 3):

Double up any single quotes like this

```
...dt.Select("[ProductName] = '" + filterValue.Replace("'", "''") + "'")[0]["ProductCode"]
```

Comment: Thanks Man, String.Replace() has solved it as per your recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ, this will make your solution simplier and more general. Otherwise you will end up with replacing single quotes (and other special characters) in the filter with escape chars.

```
DataTable dt=PullSomeDataFromProductTableDatabase();
string filterValue="Cookie's";
string productCode=dt.AsEnumerable()
                     .Where(row => row.Field<string>("ProductName") == filterValue)
                     .FirstOrDefault(row => row.Field<string>("ProductCode"));
```